# gweather_location_get_city_name: assertion 'loc != NULL' failed

Tags: location, gtk, vala

I'm trying to fetch my location using GeoClue and GWeather.

[image]

I want to display the name of my city in the blank space.

```
public class Epoch.LabelsGrid : Gtk.Grid {
    public Gtk.Label face1_label;
    public Gtk.Label face2_label;
    public Gtk.Label face3_label;
    public Gtk.Label face4_label;
    
    public GClue.Location? geo_location {get; private set; default = null;}
    public GWeather.Location location;
    private GClue.Simple simple;
    
    construct {
        face1_label = new Gtk.Label ("");
        face1_label.label = dgettext ("libgweather-locations", location.get_city_name ());
        face1_label.halign = Gtk.Align.CENTER;
        face1_label.hexpand = true;
        face1_label.margin_top = 6;
        face1_label.set_ellipsize (END);
        face1_label.set_max_width_chars (12);
        
        face2_label = new Gtk.Label ("Paris");
        face2_label.set_markup ("<span font_desc='Inter 14'><b>Paris</b></span>");
        face2_label.halign = Gtk.Align.CENTER;
        face2_label.hexpand = true;
        face2_label.margin_top = 6;
        face2_label.set_ellipsize (END);
        face2_label.set_max_width_chars (12);
        
        face3_label = new Gtk.Label ("London");
        face3_label.set_markup ("<span font_desc='Inter 14'><b>London</b></span>");
        face3_label.halign = Gtk.Align.CENTER;
        face3_label.hexpand = true;
        face3_label.margin_top = 6;
        face3_label.set_ellipsize (END);
        face3_label.set_max_width_chars (12);
        
        face4_label = new Gtk.Label ("New York");
        face4_label.set_markup ("<span font_desc='Inter 14'><b>New York</b></span>");
        face4_label.halign = Gtk.Align.CENTER;
        face4_label.hexpand = true;
        face4_label.margin_top = 6;
        face4_label.set_ellipsize (END);
        face4_label.set_max_width_chars (12);
        }
        
    public async void seek () {
        try {
            simple = yield new GClue.Simple ("com.gihhub.Suzie97.epoch", GClue.AccuracyLevel.CITY, null);
        } catch (Error e) {
            warning ("Failed to connect to GeoClue2 service: %s", e.message);
            return;
        }
        
        simple.notify["location"].connect (() => {
            on_location_updated.begin ();
        });
        
        on_location_updated.begin ();
    }
    
    public async void on_location_updated () {
        geo_location = simple.get_location ();
        
        location = location.find_nearest_city (geo_location.latitude, geo_location.longitude);
    }
}
```

This is the code.

The code compiles but while executing the program, `(com.github.Suzie97.epoch:30386): GWeather-CRITICAL **: 13:21:03.758: gweather_location_get_city_name: assertion 'loc != NULL' failed` this warning is displayed.

I found this code snippet on an app by Daniel Fore called Nimbus [(Link to nimbus repo)](https://github.com/danrabbit/nimbus)

```
 public void on_location_updated (double latitude, double longitude) {
        location = GWeather.Location.get_world ();
        location = location.find_nearest_city (latitude, longitude);
        if (location != null) {
            weather_info.location = location;
            weather_info.update ();
            stack.visible_child_name = "weather";
        }
    }
```

Do I need to do something similar to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, `gweather_location_get_city_name ()` is emitting an error because the location is NULL (`loc != NULL` is false). Look at where you're calling `get_city_name ()`. It's at the very top of your constructor, before `location` is set to anything. You need to wait until you have a location before you try to use it.

*Then* you should use something like the Nimbus code. It handles the case when `simple.get_location ()` returns NULL (if it can't find your location), and also initializes the GWeather location so it can call `find_nearest_city ()`.

Comment: I initialize the seek method at the beginning using `seek.begin ()`, And then used this code inside the `on_location_updated` method to add the city label
`
if (location != null) {
            face1_label.label = dgettext ("libgweather-locations", location.get_city_name ());
        }
`

Comment: But this warning is displayed: 
`** (com.github.Suzie97.epoch:28509): WARNING **: 21:00:48.419: Labels.vala:71: Failed to connect to GeoClue2 service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Agent rejected 'com.gihhub.Suzie97.epoch' for user '1000'. Please ensure that 'com.gihhub.Suzie97.epoch' has installed a valid com.gihhub.Suzie97.epoch.desktop file.`

Comment: But I have installed a .desktop file for the app.

Comment: `com.gihhub.Suzie97.epoch` <- you typo'd github